# Implicit vs Explicit Object-Method Memory Benchmark Differences

Tags: python, oop, memory, timeit

I ran benchmarks on two different methods of passing an object to a method and the implicit object passing took less time than the explicit method. My book says these are identical processes. What explains the difference?

First, here's the class definition:

```
class Point:
    def reset(self)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
```

So, when I run 'timeit' on each of the following two sets of code the first returns 317 ns per loop and the second returns 400 ns per loop. Here's the implicit object-method passing code, where Python passes the object to the method behind the scenes:

```
p = Point()
p.reset()
```

And here's the explicit alternative:

```
p = Point()
Point.reset(p)
```

Can someone tell me what's going on at the memory allocation level that explains the benchmark difference? Is one way more 'pythonic' than the other? Why would a programmer choose one over the other (beyond the speed)?

Thank you,

Michael

Comment: Do you really mean nanoseconds?  If so, the difference you're describing is so small as to be almost meaningless in practical terms, and could well be due to factors other than the code you show (e.g., other processes running, memory in use, etc.).  Have you reliably established that the second one is always slower?

Comment: Yes, I ran the tests 25 times each and averaged the results. I mean nanoseconds, yes.

Comment: @delnan, I used timeit. That was clearly stated right here: "So, when I run **'timeit'** on each of the following two sets of code the first returns 317 ns per loop and the second returns 400 ns per loop." Thanks you for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the first method is more pythonic, because `reset` is a method of the object `p`, instead of being a classmethod of the class `Point`.  The difference is basically, does the method `reset` belong the the class `Point`, or to objects of the class `Point`?

Using the first method makes the code more understandable, and if you wanted to do the second style, you would make it a `staticmethod` in order to indicate  the method is meant to be called from the `class` instead of from an instance (which would be somewhat poor design).

This is purely from my experience.